# How can I get from the airport in London to Middlesbrough?

Tags: budget, airports, airport-transfer

I have a flight to London and, from there, I have to go to Middlesbrough. What are the best options (bus, train, tube) when I'm on a tight budget?

Comment: Check out [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/s/London/Middlesbrough).

Comment: The £20 night bus looks like the cheapest option...

Comment: Which airport?  As mentioned, London has several.  Please edit your question to add the missing detail.

Comment: Tube? Middlesborough is lot further from London than the tube goes...

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to transfer between cities in England by public transportation is by train.  You can check trains through http://www.nationalrail.co.uk.  Trains are included in Google Transit but transfer times are not always respected and sometimes Google Transit comes up with odd proposals.

If you're on a very tight budget and willing to sacrifice comfort and time, you might find a cheaper option through intercity bus companies such as [Megabus](http://uk.megabus.com/) or [National Express](http://www.nationalexpress.com/home.aspx).  Such buses are less likely to be included in search engines like Google Transit.

Comment: I took a look at Google maps for Heathrow to Middlesbrough. It seemed quite reasonable in general concept - Piccadilly tube to Kings Cross, Virgin East Coast train to Darlington, Northern train to Middlesbrough.

Answer (score 1):

The correct direction is the [transit planner](https://tfl.gov.uk). London has six airports and Middlesbrough is a 170K people town so you need to enter the actual coordinates because we do not know them. Alternatively, Google Maps is always at your service and for the UK it has extensive public transit directions. Finally, are you sure you don't want to fly to some place closer like Manchester, Leeds or Newcastle?

Comment: You've linked the Transport for London travel planner but Middlesborough is (as you of course know) a good deal outside London and possibly whatever London airport the OP lands at may be as well.

Comment: Aye and that planner covers the entirety of UK. Do not believe the header. Try it.

Comment: I don't know how much of the UK it covers, but after reading that I tried to plan a journey from Land's End to John O'Groats, which is quite possible on public transport - even using only buses! It could not even tell where these places were. I tried it again using postcodes (TR19 7AA to KW1 4YR) and it failed again to find a journey. I am not sure it covers the _entirety_ of the UK...

Comment: It covers the OP's case enough https://goo.gl/n1AuKK

Answer (score 1):

Take tube into London - less than an hour -£6.00

Then nicest, quickest and most expensive, is train.

- Train London to Middlesborough: 3 hours - £60 approx

Express bus takes longer.

- Megabus London to Middlesborough: 5 or 6 hours - £10

In both cases you will need to book in advance to get best fares. Trains in particular tend to have horrible "walk-up" fares.

Answer (score 1):

As a [smoggie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoggie) the best way to get to Middlesbrough from London is by train. There are no longer any direct flights from London Heathrow to Durham Tees Valley Airport (Teesside Airport) and its not looking likley until Heathrow build a third runway.

There's no longer any direct train services from London to Middlesbrough either but there are two services which run close to Middlesbrough and local train connections are readily available directly into Middlesbrough station from them. All services to Middlesbrough and the surrounding area (North East England) operate out of London Kings Cross Station which is accessible from the London Tube network.

1. [Grand Central](https://www.grandcentralrail.com/) is usually the cheaper of the two options. They have 5 direct trains per day (Monday - Saturday) and 4 on a Sunday to Eaglescliffe which is two stops away from Middlesbrough on the Darlington - Saltburn local line.
2. [Virgin Trains East Coast](https://www.virgintrainseastcoast.com/) offer more services but they are usually more expensive than Grand Central. Most trains from London to Edinburgh stop at Darlington. There you can hop on the twice hourly connecting service to Middlesbrough which will be going to Saltburn. The same service as option 1.

As with all UK long distance train services, the more in advance you book your tickets the cheaper it is.

There are direct busses from London to Middlesbrough which should be cheaper than train, but slower. London Victoria Coach Station direct services operated by [Megabus](https://uk.megabus.com/) and [National Express](http://www.nationalexpress.com/home.aspx) which go directly without changes to Middlesbrough Bus Station.

Middlesbrough is a great town which is widely misinterpreted in the UK media. Ignore what you may hear. The people are very friendly and the surrounding area is stunning.